# Incorrect syntax near ',' SQL Server Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax

I am having the following error on my SQL Server Query I don't know how to overcome it Because I tried my best Please help me getting out of it:

```
      CREATE TABLE d3 as SELECT sessionnumber, sessioncount, LEFT(timespent, 1) , COUNT 
      as cnt
      FROM clusters
      GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

The following error is generated:

```
   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
   Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Please help me! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not SQL Server syntax.  You want `select into`:

```
  SELECT sessionnumber, sessioncount, LEFT(timespent, 1) as TimeSpentCode, COUNT(*) as cnt
  into d3
  FROM clusters
  GROUP BY sessionnumber, sessioncount, LEFT(timespent, 1);
```

All the columns need to have names.  So I added one for the third column.

And, `group by` does not accept positional indicators in SQL Server, so I replaced them with the appropriate expressions.

Comment: @MikeChristensen . . . No.  In fact, it assumes that `d3` does *not* exist.  If you want to insert into an existing table, use `insert . . . select`.

Answer (score 0):

You have the word count instead of count(something).